# retrieve Facebook Comments from the URL using Graph API and FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve comments by given url, e.g.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://example.com/
```

However, when I substitute a link, I get an empty set, even comments exist on the page..

Wonder if it's related to oauth and if I have to provide access token or smth..I am using js, I would appreciate if you would help with any samples how to retrieve comments by URL or by commentID using FQL

UPDATE QUESTION:

How some url work with API without any tokens being passed, where other don't work?

example: http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http://techcrunch.com/2011/09/20/digg-experiments-with-topic-newsrooms-aggregates-news-by-most-meaningful-stories/ (works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the site has a comments object associated to it, you'll see the comments. Otherwise you will see what you're seeing, an empty dataset. Example ...

First, graph [TimHortons](https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://timhortons.com/) ... then visit the [Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) Plugin ... Enter in "TimHortons.com" in the domain ... Leave a comment ... now visit the graph [TimHortons](https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://timhortons.com/) again ...

See the comments? Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a same POST api for posting new comments

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create facebook app for your website and then include the following meta tag entry on your page:

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{your-app-id}" />

only comments added after adding the meta tag will appear in your url.

To create an app on facebook, go to developers.facebook.com. Under `Apps` tab you will find an option to create the app. If you're not as yet registered as a developer, it will first ask you to register as a developer.